# exporting own eclipse plugin makes trouble

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, export, rcp

I've finished creating an eclipse plugin. testing it inside eclipse running another eclipse instance everything works fine. therefore I wanted to export it and install it in my 'main' eclipse.

I ran export -> plugin development -> deployable plugins and fragments -> chose my plugin and used directory (creating a jar file).

After exporting I copied the .jar file to my eclipse dropins folder and restarted.

but what worked like a charm running another eclipse instance from the run command inside eclipse itself doesn't work at all after installing my plugin.

I'm using

```
popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?before=additions
```

from Manifest.xml

```
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
org.eclipse.core.runtime,
org.eclipse.core.resources,
org.eclipse.ui.ide,
org.eclipse.core.filesystem
```

extensions:

```
extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus"
extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands"
```

to create a popup menu entry inside Navigator/Project Explorer et cetera.
If I right click anything now the whole popup menu is empty, sometimes it shows a few entries sometimes none at all. same goes for the file -> new menu or anything else. 
seems I'm killing the whole menu / popup bars.
hope you're able to provide me with some help.

sorry for the long summary but thought I'd rather explain everything in detail. if you need further information please just tell me.

Comment: Are there any messages in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory?

Comment: nothing related to my plugin only some entries about my missing inet connection (http proxy authentification required)

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider to create a feature for your plugin. Then you can create an update site in eclipse and add your feature to the update site. After that build the update site and export it to the file system. Then you can install your feature into every eclipse with the Install new Software function. You can even publish the folder to a web server and every user can update his eclipse installation with your update site.